# R: assign group based on 24 hr time frame

Tags: r, datetime, grouping, data-manipulation

I have this dataset:

```
    test <- data.frame("Event" = c("A", "B", "C","D","E"),"startTime" = c("2017-08-01 00:37:27", "2017-08-01 00:44:32", "2017-08-01 23:30:00","2017-08-01 23:55:47", "2017-08-02 01:00:00" ), "endTime" = c("2017-08-01 20:13:13", "2017-08-01 21:30:45", "2017-08-02 09:00:00","2017-08-01 23:56:47", "2017-08-02 04:18:38"), "Bin" = c(1,1,2,1,2))
```

I want to create a column Bin where you assign value 1 to n based on 24 hour frame of the startTime and endTime. For example, event A and B belong to Bin (group) #1 because they both start on 2017-08-01 and end on the same date. However, event C belongs to bin #2 because it ends on the next day instead of 2017-08-01. Event D belongs to bin #2 because it starts and ends on 2017-08-02 and so on.

I do not know how to properly assign the group value based on this logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: So in determining the Bin, only end date matters?

Comment: Yes it does matter

Comment: I don't think the rule is unambiguously articulated, but perhaps `test$Bin2 <- as.integer(as.factor(as.Date(test$endTime, tz = "")))`.

Comment: Hi that doesn’t produce the right group value assignment and it doesn’t start with value 1

Comment: What is bin if endTime is 8-04 aka, is bin the number of days from the first endtime, or just an entry number based on end time?

Comment: Bin would be 4 because it depends on the endTime

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

test %>%
mutate(Bin = if_else(as.Date(test$endTime) - as.Date(test$startTime) == 0, 1,2 )) -> df
```

Comment: Hi this works if there’re inly 2 groups and I have bigger dataset with n groups as there are more days. I just listed 2 groups as example. Sorry I should’ve been more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here, bin2 is the number of days from the min of endTime.

```
test %>%
    mutate(bin2 = as.integer(as.Date(endTime) - min(as.Date(endTime))) + 1)
```

Comment: That doesn’t work because it will produce mostly 1 and occasionaly 2. But there will be event afterevent C that belong to the first timeframe (bin) so you can’t use cumsum to group value by first occurence of 2

Comment: Can you include this event C in the test dataframe?